# Turn Pandas Dataframe into LSTM input tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, keras, neural-network, lstm

I want to turn my pandas dataframe into an input tensor which is then going to be feed to an LSTM network.

The sequence is inside one of the columns in the dataframe in a list form. Additionally, there are two values that are associated with the sequence, namely the duration and user_cluster_id.

Dataframe looks like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3knX.png)

I managed to extract the individual values of the sequence at each timestep and turn each of them into an input tensor, but I am guessing that it is wrong since I am breaking the sequence.

The pandas dataframe name is travel_history below is what I did:

```
input_seqs = []
output_seqs = []
for i in range(travel_history.shape[0]):
    user_cluster = travel_history.iloc[i,:]
    cluster_id = user_cluster['sequence'].tolist()
    user_class = user_cluster['user_cluster_id']
    duration = int(user_cluster['duration'])

    for i,cluster in enumerate(cluster_id):
        if i < len(cluster_id)-1:
            input_seqs.append([user_class,i, duration,cluster])
            output_seqs.append([cluster_id[i+1]])
```

I expect an output that sort of looks like this: [sequence#1[cluster, duration,user_cluster_id].

Instead, the actual output looks like this [2, 0, 8, 87] where each value corresponds to the [user_cluster_id, timestep, duration, cluster]

Comment: What about not iterating through the data and just map your column and to an np.array and after that use pad_sequences to prepare you sequences for the LSTM? e.g.
`features = df['sequence'].map(lambda x: np.array(x)[-seq_length:]).values`

`X =  pad_sequences(features, maxlen=seq_length)`